# What does "Unknown Error" mean when `gcloud datastore export`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I wanna back-up data in Cloud Datastore into Cloud Storage, and executed a command like this:

```
gcloud datastore export gs://some_bucket/path/ \
--namespaces=foo --kinds='Bar' --project some_project
```

But it **just** return

```
ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.export) UNKNOWN: Unknown Error.
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong, and neither find solution to this.
What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

`Unknown Error` most likely means `Bad Parameter(s)` ...

the `/` at the end of the path could be the reason - or probably, because the `--namespaces` lack the single `'` quotes; those are also case-sensitive. that's at least what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/export) would hint for.

```
gcloud datastore export gs://some_bucket/path \
--namespaces='foo' --kinds='Bar' --project some_project
```

... there's a `--verbosity` parameter.

Comment: When 'verbosity="debug"', its http response is below.

Comment: `<{'status': '500', 'content-length': '95', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 21 Sep 2018 03:04:15 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Unknown Error.",
    "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
}
>`

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct. The reason you are receiving this error is most likely related with the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#permissions).

> For all export requests, both the account making the request and the
>   App Engine default service account for the GCP project, must have an
>   IAM role that grants the following permissions for your Cloud Storage
>   bucket:
>
> ```
> storage.buckets.get
> storage.objects.create    
> storage.objects.list
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a testing project, and apparently I didn't enable the storage in that firebase project... wasted a good 4 hours on this‍♂️